# Is the use of elastic net for variable selection purposes a form of data dredging?

Tags: feature-selection, elastic-net

Is the use of elastic net for variable selection purposes a form of data dredging? I switched from using stepwise regression procedure for variable selection to elastic net, but I actually do not know whether the latter is also a form of data dredging.

Comment: *Data dredging* aka data mining are pejorative terms which have lost most of their force and meaning in an AI/ML world.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, elastic net is a form of data dredging.  It represents *safer* data dredging because during the selection process it carries along with it a penalty that "remembers" the context.  Like lasso and ridge regression, a parameter will have a larger penalty when there are more candidate predictors.  So the coefficient for selected variables will be properly smaller than had only the selected variables be put into a model and no penalization used.  For elastic net, and worse for lasso, perhaps the most severe dredging has to do with the low probability that these methods find the "right" variables.